# Inno Setup: cursor doesn't change when I press outside the installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, mouse-cursor

I made an installer using Inno Setup and inserted a code to change the mouse cursor to a custom one once its started and to return to default one I exit it, but I wanted for the mouse to change to default one i click outside of the installer even if it is still running.

This is my code:

```
[Code]
const
  OCR_NORMAL = 32512;

function SetSystemCursor(hcur: LongWord; id: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'SetSystemCursor@user32.dll stdcall';
function LoadCursorFromFile(lpFileName: string): LongWord;
  external 'LoadCursorFromFileW@user32.dll stdcall';
function CopyIcon(hIcon: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'CopyIcon@user32.dll stdcall';
function LoadCursor(hInstance: LongWord; lpCursorName: LongWord): LongWord;
    external 'LoadCursorA@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  OriginalCursor: LongWord;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  PathToCursorFile: string;
  Cursor: LongWord;
begin
  // Remember the original custom
  OriginalCursor := CopyIcon(LoadCursor(0, OCR_NORMAL));

  // Load our cursor
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MyCursor.cur')
  PathToCursorFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyCursor.cur');
  Cursor := LoadCursorFromFile(Graphics\Images\PixelCursor.cur);
  SetSystemCursor(Cursor, OCR_NORMAL);
end;


procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  // Restore original cursor on exit
  SetSystemCursor(OriginalCursor, OCR_NORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: Then stop setting the system cursor and set the window cursor instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `SetCursor` in [`user32.dll`](https://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/user32_dll.html), you can use it instead of `SetSystemCursor`.

This is example from Microsoft Docs: [Using Cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors).

Comment: I tried the `SetCursor` function but it didn't do anything